# USB keyboard and mouse mouse control end after login

Tags: ubuntu, usb, keyboard, mouse

Ubuntu 18.04:  When the login screen appears the USB keyboard and mouse work fine.  I select an account and enter its password.  As soon as the desktop for the given account appears, the mouse and keyboard input seems locked out.  I'm very new to Linux (trying to learn it).

This began right after some packages were either installed or updated requiring a reboot.  Now I'm not certain what packages they were.  I'm desperate to solve the problem as I can do nothing until at least one account works.  I don't even know if it is a USB issue or an input issue or what.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Since your input works until your user session starts after logging in through your greeter ( a graphical interface at login where you type in your username and password). In linux you can access the terminal before you log in, by hitting ALT+CTRL+[F1-F6], and you will see a black screen asking you  for a username and then your password. Before trying to do anything else, next time you start your OS, instead of typing in your username/pass, hit ALT+CTRL+F2 and login as your administrator user , and then type in and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and allow it to finish.

Comment: BarBar1234, thanks for the input.  I followed your instructions exactly and unfortunately am still getting the same results as before.  One of the things I was trying to install earlier was support for VNC and/or RDP.  Could something have gotten messed up in a way that my mouse/keyboard input was being directed to come from somewhere else?  This is the only guess I have at this point.  Otherwise I am lost as to why it works until after a user logs in.  Thanks.

Comment: No, the VNC or RDP would not affect it, as your usb keyboard and mouse have a discreete `/dev/input/event*` device attached to it. If it was just the keyboard or just the mouse, then perhaps it could be some input redirection issue due to the drivers, but since we are talking about two different usb connections, it is very unlikely.  After you log in (when your mouse and keyboard becomes disabled) can you try the ALT+CTRL+[F1-F6] again, and report whether it gets recognized or not. If it does not, then the issue will likely be related to power settings for your usb ports in `/sys` .

Comment: Also, get the ALT+CTRL+F terminal (preferebly after logging in if your keyboard recognized the key combo), and please run `sudo dmesg -l err > log_dmesg_err.txt` , and `sudo dmesg | grep -i usb  > log_dmesg_usb.txt` and `sudo service udev status > log_udev_status.txt` and `sudo udevadm info /sys/class/hidraw/hidraw* > log_hid.txt` and `sudo udevadm info /sys/class/input/* > log_inputs.txt` and `sudo udevadm info /sys/bus/usb/devices/* > log_udev_usb.txt`. Finally, run `for l in log_*.txt; do echo $l;cat -n $l ; echo -e '\n';done | curl -F 'sprunge=<-' http://sprunge.us` and post the link.

Comment: Here is a sprunge link: http://sprunge.us/3i5h7K that has the command list for generating and uploading the log files. This way you only need to write down the end part [`3i5h7K`] of this link and Run from the console terminal the following command: `wget sprunge.us/3i5h7K -O comms_list` which will copy  it  to your current folder, and then run:   `. comms_list`   which runs all commands in a file. You will be asked for your password when you run   `. comms_list` because of `dmesg` permissions. The output of the command will be another sprunge link that you can then add to your original post.

Comment: I was able to identify the two packages that were installed prior to the issue arising -- both had to do with X11 (not sure whether they were client, server or related to both).  I uninstalled them then ran update & full-upgrade per your original message.  It solved the problem.  I'm not sure how it did what it did, but that was the cause.  Thanks much!

Comment: @Brook Wilson dude! Share the package names you uninstalled! I’m in the same boat here!